# Why in this WordPress theme I can't see the Main Menu?

Tags: php, theme-development, menus, themes, twitter-bootstrap

I am pretty new in WP (I came from Joomla) and I have the following problem.

I have installed WordPress on my server and if I use one of the included theme (such as the **Twenty Thirteen** theme) when I open the website I see it and under the header I can see the classic horizontal **Main Menu** containing the voice **Sample Page**, ok...this is the right behavior.

Then I have installed the following theme **http://bootstrapwp.rachelbaker.me/** that is a WP theme that use BootStrap (I think that it could be a good start point to develop a personal theme using BootStrap CSS framework).

I install it but when I activate the theme I obtain this result: http://onofri.org/WP_BootStrap/

As you can see the website is shown but seems that **there is not the Main Menu** as in the others preinstalled theme.

Why? What could be the problem?

I opened the **header.php** file of this theme and here I find the following lines of code:

```
                <?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a>
            <?php wp_nav_menu(
                    array(
                        'menu' => 'main-menu',
                        'container_class' => 'nav-collapse collapse',
                        'menu_class' => 'nav',
                        'fallback_cb' => '',
                        'menu_id' => 'main-menu',
                        'walker' => new Bootstrapwp_Walker_Nav_Menu()
                    )
                ); ?>
```

So it seems to me that the main menu navigation bar is present in this theme.

Do you have some ideas to solve my problem?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: have you created a menu under appearance > menus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Appearance > Menus & create a new menu called main-menu

That should fix the problem.